# dask array map_blocks, with differently shaped dask array as argument

Tags: python-3.x, dask

I'm trying to use `dask.array.map_blocks` to process a dask array, using a second dask array with different shape as an argument. The use case is firstly running some peak finding on a 2-D stack of images (4-dimensions), which is returned as a 2-D dask array of np.objects. Ergo, the two first dimensions of the two dask arrays are the same. The peaks are then used to extract intensities from the 4-dimensional dataset. In the code below, I've omitted the peak finding part. Dask version 1.0.0.

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

def test_processing(data_chunk, position_chunk):
    output_array = np.empty(data_chunk.shape[:-2], dtype='object')
    for index in np.ndindex(data_chunk.shape[:-2]):
        islice = np.s_[index]
        intensity_list = []
        data = data_chunk[islice]
        positions = position_chunk[islice]
        for x, y in positions:
            intensity_list.append(data[x, y])
        output_array[islice] = np.array(intensity_list)
    return output_array

data = da.random.random(size=(4, 4, 10, 10), chunks=(2, 2, 10, 10))
positions = np.empty(data.shape[:-2], dtype='object')
for index in np.ndindex(positions.shape):
    positions[index] = np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2)

data_output = da.map_blocks(test_processing, data, positions, dtype=np.object,
                            chunks=(2, 2), drop_axis=(2, 3))
data_output.compute()
```

This gives the error `ValueError: Can't drop an axis with more than 1 block. Please use`atop`instead.`, which I'm guessing is due to `positions` having 3 dimensions, while `data` has 4 dimensions.

The same function, but without the `positions` dask array works fine.

```py
import numpy as np
import dask.array as da

def test_processing(data_chunk):
    output_array = np.empty(data_chunk.shape[:-2], dtype='object')
    for index in np.ndindex(data_chunk.shape[:-2]):
        islice = np.s_[index]
        intensity_list = []
        data = data_chunk[islice]
        positions = [[5, 2], [1, 3]]
        for x, y in positions:
            intensity_list.append(data[x, y])
        output_array[islice] = np.array(intensity_list)
    return output_array

data = da.random.random(size=(4, 4, 10, 10), chunks=(2, 2, 10, 10))

data_output = da.map_blocks(test_processing, data, dtype=np.object,
                            chunks=(2, 2), drop_axis=(2, 3))
data_computed = data_output.compute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed in more recent versions of `dask`: running the same code on version 2.3.0 of `dask` works fine.